# stopping sharepoint workflow programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, api

well the thing is i am having a scheduled script that checks some changes in a different database (Oracle), if the change happens

I need to cancel /kill/ stop a workflow if it is in progress on a specific item of my list

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try, but the [SPWorkflowManager.CancelWorkflow Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager.cancelworkflow.aspx)  should do what you want to do: "Cancels the specified workflow instance."

I hope it works and solves your problem.